# The sdl2-config script installed by SDL could not be found

Tags: tar, configure, sdl

I had tried to install archive.tar.gz file, on fresh installed linux OS and it give me this error message.
after i had apply

```
lm@debian:/$ sudo apt-get install libsdl2-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
.................................
Setting up libsdl2-dev:amd64 (2.26.5+dfsg-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.11.2-2) ...
lm@debian:/$
```

So, i had tried to install SDL image itself,from it's source archive ,
and it has  successfully installed, here the output tail of MAKE INSTALL command:

````
```
cmake/SDL2_image
/usr/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/include/SDL2'
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 SDL_image.h'/usr/local/include/SDL2'
/usr/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig'
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 SDL2_image.pc '/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/lm/Downloads/SDL2_image-2.6.3'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/lm/Downloads/SDL2_image-2.6.3'
lm@debian:~/Downloads/SDL2_image-2.6.3$ cd ../tuxtype_w_fonts-1.8.0/

```
````

and after the retry to configure the application,
i has the same error, that SDL image is shorted.

````
```

lm@debian:~/Downloads/tuxtype_w_fonts-1.8.0$ sudo ./configure
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

.................................
checking for sdl-config... /usr/bin/sdl-config
checking for SDL - version >= 1.2.0... yes
checking for native Win32... no
checking for IMG_Load in -lSDL_image... no
configure: error: SDL_image not found!    http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image
lm@debian:~/Downloads/tuxtype_w_fonts-1.8.0$ 

```
````

but while configuring, it give me the same error message.

i had go by the link in message, but didn't find, how to include the sdl image to appropriate folder because of my unexperience.

the question is,

How i can fix this,
if to run ./config after to SDL image install,
I need SDL image installed already?

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.